# MVC page design using caching for best performance and UX

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, mongodb

I have a album page (using ASPNET MVC + MongoDB) which has following parts:

#1 List of thumbnails displayed as a grid 
  Note: I load few fields for each video in the video album: url, length, caption,  tags. If user hovers over thumbnail I show some of them.

#2 Then I have related albums

#3 Then I have List details

#4 Then I have current video details (including description which can be 5K characters)

#5 Then all comments of the current video.

As you can see list of thumbnails, related albums, list details are same for all videos.

But video details, video comments are different for each videos.

I NEED TO STREAM VIDEO, GET VIDEO DETAILS & COMMENTS EACH TIME USER CLICKS DIFFERENT THUMBNAIL

WHAT IS THE BEST WAY TO DO IT?

Option 1: url redirect user for each click (will cause reloading of common pieces)

Option 2: ajax to load comments and VIDEO details & update page (more coding)

Is there a way to leverage caching common pieces?

Please share your thoughts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is in scope I would probably also look into using one of the many framework for creating a Single Page Application, like Backbone (which I happen to like like a lot).

If it is only a caching solution that you are looking for, MVC has an [OutputCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) attribute that can be applied to a Controller or to single Actions and allows fine tune and managing of caching behvaiours server side, client side, parameter based etc. etc.

Comment: I don't want to cache the entire action. As I said I only need to cache those common parts (list details, thumbnails & related lists) of the page. If I cache the entire action (page), how will it work?

Comment: I can't use output cache as well after reading some articles. The problem is that I can have 100 thousands of albums and I just can't cache for each of them. Server will run out of memory.

Comment: You can force the cache on the Client only if I recall correctly, so each client will only cache the small sections of album it has seen. Anyway, if caching is not an option, the alternative is to keep the data on the UI and use Ajax to refresh the changing parts...

Comment: I will be using Ajax page refresh.